# Bonferroni correction when comparing sub-group with rest of the group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, group-differences, bonferroni

I am working with 4 machines that test products and record a value during each test.  I have ~ 1000 records from each, and some recorded values look like: -0.67, 0.3, 5.7, 2.3, -0.78, 5.2, 5.8, 9, 2.1, 3.2, -0.34.  I want to determine if there is a specific machine that is calibrated differently, i.e. is recording significantly different values from the others.

For this, I am looking to perform pair-wise t-tests (assumption of Normality holding true) - each time comparing measurements from one machine to those from the others.  So basically, Machine 1 vs (Machine 2 + 3 + 4), Machine 2 vs (Machine 1 + 3 + 4), and so on.

Is this a correct way to approach this problem or are there better solutions?  Also, would I need to use the Bonferroni correction with these tests?

P.S - I glanced upon a somewhat similar post on the forum but that dint answer all my questions ([Mean of one group vs. the rest of the sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/mean-of-one-group-vs-the-rest-of-the-sample)).  For instance, ANOVA and post-hoc tests would give me pair-wise comparisons and answer questions like Machine 1 is different from Machine 2, Machine 3 with 4, and so on - not exactly the question I seek to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test those effects using linear contrasts (see http://onlinestatbook.com/2/tests_of_means/specific_comparisons.html) Bonferroni corrections would be recommended. Alternatively, you could compare one group with each of the others using Dunnett's test (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett's_test) which controls the Type I error rate.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLane.  I noticed that my data was not normal so Specific Comparisons wouldn't help.  Also, I intend to automate detection of the outlier machine - so it is not possible for me to analyze the (possibly non-normal) distributions and apply transformations to make it normal.  I was researching a little bit and feel left with 2 options - the Mann Whitney U Test, and Bootstrapping my distribution to make it normal.  My goal is to minimize Type II error, so a less powerful test will also work.  Do you think I am thinking in the right direction with regards to the 2 tests shortlisted?

Comment: Do you have inputs on the above problem?  I know that automation is difficult especially since there can be so many unknowns in the data, which is also why I am leaning toward Bootstrapping method at the moment.

Comment: Bootstrapping is fine but unless your non-normality is extreme  and you can't find a satisfactory transformation, I think the Dunnett's test would be OK.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs David.  I looked at my data last week and there's a lot of skewness and multi-modality in my distributions.  Unfortunately, since I am also automating the comparisons, it will be extremely difficult for me to apply any suitable transformations to my distributions.  Hence I am looking to use Bootstrapping now.